# SpringBoot: System.loadLibrary run twice

Tags: spring-boot

I have **Spring Boot** app version **1.5.3.RELEASE**

In the main class I call **System.loadLibrary**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class BlaApplication {

  static {
      System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Loading Lib");
      System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(BlaApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

When app starts **System.loadLibrary is called twice**:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Loading Lib
11:10:51.766 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
11:10:51.771 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/]
11:10:51.771 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/Users/tomas/workspace/formater/formater-backend/target/classes/]
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Loading Lib
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.13.2/share/OpenCV/java/libopencv_java2413.dylib already loaded in another classloader
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1907)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
at com.martoma.BlaApplication.<clinit>(BlaApplication.java:16)
...
```

**Why is it called twice?**

Comment: There is probably another class  that at runtime loads the library.  If you remove this loading, is the library loaded ?

Comment: but problem is that this particular static block runs twice - if I put logger above System.loadLibrary(...) I got 2 logs in console

Comment: If I remove System.loadLibrary(...), the lib is not loaded in app at all and any call on OpenCV fails

Comment: I guess that is due to the fact that a class proxy is created for `BlaApplication`. Resulting in 2 different classes with the same static block and thus being initialized twice.

Comment: How to avoid that?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to put the **System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);** in its own config class:

```
@Configuration
public class LibLoading {
    static {
       System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java Exception Handling – UnsatisfiedLinkError

```
static {

     try {
            // Attempt to load library.
            System.loadLibrary("XXXXXX"); 
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError error) {
            // Output expected UnsatisfiedLinkErrors.
        } catch (Error | Exception error) {
            // Output unexpected Errors and Exceptions.
        }
}
```